# Solve for all $z$ in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

$z^2 - (4 + 6i)z - 4 + 12i = 0$

How would you go about solving this equation? My first try was to substitute $z$ with $a+bi$ and expand the expressions and then try grouping the real and imaginary to try and find an answer, but I can't seem to come to the right answer

Comment: Hint: quadratic formula.

Comment: Use the quadratic formula. It works also for complex coefficients